# Java - adding functionality to all classes inheriting a specific interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, generic-collections

I'm sorry to say that I cannot describe my problem more to the core or more abstractly. I feel the best way to explain my problem is by means of this quite specific example.

I want to define a function 'readCollection' which would parse a String and give me a specific collection of a specific type, based on how I call the function.

For example, I would like to use it as such:

```
ArrayList<Foo> fb = readCollection("Foo1\n Foo2\n Foo3\n");
```

or

```
LinkedList<Bar> fb = readCollection("Bar1\n Bar2\n Bar3\n");
```

Of course I have defined an interface for every class which has a 'read' method for reading one instance ("Bar..").

I am caught between a couple of problems:

-naturally the function readCollection should be a static function, but an interface cannot have static methods.

-the method readCollection should return a new object of type Foo or Bar or etc, but I 'cannot instantiate the type', which is generically defined in the class i have defined readCollection.

-supposing the method isn't defined statically, i cannot call it without making reference to a specific object of that type, which I cannot do because of the previous point.

How can I write my method without copying it for each Foo and Bar etc.?

I seem to have found a solution myself, but it is very ugly and nasty.

I now have

```
public interface Readable<T> {
    public T read(String str); }
```

and

```
public class ReadCollection<T extends Readable<T>> {
    public Collection<T> read(File file, Collection<T> ts, T t) {
        ...
        ts.add(t.read(strLine));
        ...
        return ts; 
} }
```

and

```
public class Bars extends ReadCollection<Bar>{
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Bars().read(new File("fake/path"), new ArrayList<Bar>(), new Bar()); }
```

Here I sent along new instances of an ArrayList, to give back the result in, and for Bar, in order to refer te the method 'read'. I cannot see how I could have avoided that.

Please tell me there is a better way. 
Somewhere I'd like for me to feel very dumb in hindsight.

Comment: in Java 8, interfaces can have static methods, and default implementations ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey : awesome! Can't wait for it to be out! Heard it's gonna be somewhere mid 2013...

Comment: The rumour is Summer 2013. Given that it has two branches currently (with different releases) and looks like there is more than a few kinks in it, I imagine it might be delayed to improve the quality of the first release. They don't want the bad press that Java 7 had in the early days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad that I'm able to tell you that I have found the final and best answer myself, with the help of your comment (@stevevls) and the help of a friend.

I now have

```
public interface Reader {
    public Reader read(String str); }
```

so I've removed the generic argument, shich was unneccesary

```
public class ReadCollection { // no generic class!
public static <R extends Reader, C extends Collection<R>> // generic static function! 
        C readColl(File file, Class<? extends C> collClass, Class<? extends R> readClass) {
    C ts = collClass.newInstance()
        Reader t = readClass.newInstance()
        ...
        ts.add(readClass.cast(t.read(strLine)));
        ...
        return ts; 
} }
```

and, now I can call the function from anywhere:

```
ArrayList<Point> l = ReadCollection.readColl(new File("examples/ex1.csv"), ArrayList.class, Point.class);
```

(assuming Point implements Reader / has the read-method...)

without sending along a new instance, and moer importantly: without ever having to extend the class ReadCollection anywhere.

the problem that the read method cannot be static, cause it is defined in the interface Reader, persists. This is the reason I use readClass.newInstance() etc.

Still I think this solution is not so ugly anymore.

Do you guys agree this is a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

Think about splitting up the parsing/construction from the object itself.  In many cases, the two are very separate concerns.

You're on the right track, but I would recommend:

1. Don't have your element types inherit from the `Readable` interface
2. Rename the `Readable` interface to `Reader`
3. Implement a `Reader` for each type you would like to parse.
4. Update the signature of your `ReadCollection.read` method to take a `Reader` instead of a `T`

You'll then have:

```
public class ReadCollection<T,C extends Collection<T>> {
    public C read(File file, C ts, Reader<T> reader) {
        ...
        ts.add(reader.read(strLine));
        ...
        return ts; 
    } 
}
```

This gives you a good separation of concerns that should solve all the problems you listed.

Comment: You probably want a parameter `C extends Collection<T>`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline an excellent point...i had overlooked that, but i've now added that parameterization.

Comment: It would be better applied to the method. In fact they both would, although possibly it would be more useful to make `reader` an instance field and keep `T` where it is.

Comment: I had already found a solution, but didn't like it. The problem I had eventually was that it was ugly - the passing along of `new ArrayList<Bar>(), new Bar()` was my eventual problem. You did not solve that. You made a small though good improvement to my code, as I see it.

Comment: @TimKuipers to a certain extent, you won't be able to get away without some sort of extra work on the collection.  you could always pass `Class<? extends Collection>` as your second argument and instantiate it via the `newInstance()` method.  the collections API specifies that all collections should have a public no-args constructor, so in theory that's a safe operation.

Answer (score 1):

APIs should be defined through interfaces.

Shared implementations should be through abstract base classes.

So how do you use an abstract base class without losing the benefits of an interface?

Easy! Simply have the abstract base class implement the interface.

Then any class that needs the shared functionality can extend the abstract base class, but you do not tie yourself in to any specific implementation, which will be handy for writing unit tests, for example.

Comment: I agree, sounds like you need an abstract class here.

Comment: @BillMitchell  
Any class that needs the shared functionality == any class that implements the interface Collection! There is basically one implementation (which makes use if the Iterator that collections share) which would work for any collection of elements of any type which conforms to the Readable/Reader interface, so which has a read method. Your comment doesn't apply.